# Outlook Web Access OWA not updating real time

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-web-app

I have some users that when they update their inbox via an outlook 2010 client, the changes they made take a long time to update on Outlook Web Access (OWA). When testing, via another outlook 2010 client I see the changes to the inbox are updated real time inside of OWA.

The environment is - 2 CAS/HT servers in a NLB array. 2 MBX servers in a DAG. All 2008 R2, and exchange 2010.

Having a tough time isolating this issue, while I feel that its client side, its happening to more than 3 users at current (happened sporadically to more users last week).

I am unable to find errors to correlate to this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the problem users using Outlook in cached mode? If so, that might explain the delay in seeing things in OWA. Cached mode caches operations and "batches" them to the server. Cached mode is definitely not "real time".

Comment: I have had the affected users, disable cached mode, and re-enable cached mode, unfortunately the issue persists. 

Also got some new information... An email received in OWA is not showing up until an hour later in the users outlook client. Which leads me to believe the outlook client is not updating the mailbox, and not receiving emails timely. I am thinking the issue is more client side, or network related, but still dont have supporting evidence as other apps work fine. Had affected user blow away profile, issue still persists though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found one of our CAS servers had a different encryption setting than the other via the command 
    get-rpcClientAccess | ft server, EncryptionRequired –auto

After that was fixed, the whole exchange environment was rebooted CAS/HT servers than the MBX servers.

Issue appears to be resolved at current.